# A set $A\subset\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ such that $\left(\bigcap_{S_k\in A}S_k\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{S_k\notin A}S^c_k\right)$ is always infinite

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory

Let $\omega$ be the set of natural numbers. Does there exist a set $A\subset \mathcal{P}(\omega)$ (the powerset of $\omega$) such that, for every group of finitely many subsets $S_1,S_2,\cdots,S_n$ of $\omega$, we have that
$$ \left(\bigcap_{S_k\in A} S_k\right)\cap \left(\bigcap_{S_k\notin A} S^c_k\right)$$
is infinite ($c$ denotes the complement set)?

For a subset of $\omega$, one and only one of it and its complement should be in $A$. Two sets that differ by only finitely many elements should have the same status in $A$. But what's more can be said about $A$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are in fact $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ such $A$.

An "filter on $X$" is a set $F\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ such that:

1. $X\in F,\emptyset\notin F$
2. If $a\in F$ and $a\subseteq b\subseteq X$ then $b\in F$
3. If $a,b\in F$ then $a\cap b\in F$

A very special filter on any infinite set $X$ is called the "Frechet filter", which is $F=\{a\subseteq X\mid X\setminus a \text{ is finite}\}$ (you can check it is a filter)

An *ultra*filter on $X$ is a filter $F$ such that if $a\subseteq X$ then either $a\in F$ or $X\setminus a\in F$.

---

An important result called "the ultrafilters lemma" states that if $F$ is a filter on $X$, then there exists an ultrafilter $U$ on $X$ such that $F\subseteq U$.

In particular, let $X$ be $\omega$ and $F$ be the Frechet filter, then there exists an ultrafilter on $\omega$ that contains the Frechet filter, an ultrafilters that contains the Frechet filter are called "non-principal ultrafilter".

It is not too hard to verify that any non-principal ultrafilter will satisfy the conditions you put, and any set satisfy your conditions is a non-principal ultrafilter.

It is possible, but much harder, to show that if $X$ is infinite, then there are $2^{2^{|X|}}$ non-principal ultrafilters on $X$.

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks! :)